# Addslashes only escapes simple quotes

Tags: php, json, string, quotes

I have a few string variables in my PHP code, which look like the following :

```
"A piece of text with sometimes 'simple quotes' in it, and most important,
some parts "between double quotes" inside the string itself, playing the role
of quotations marks"
```

Unfortunately, I get this data from a database, and need to put it in a JSON string format. When I loop over the JSON object generated by `json_encode` (I get the data as associative array with PDO and then encode it) and use `addslashes` for every string in the loop, only the simple quotes get escaped.

(I know it is not well-formed, but this is how I get it from the database...)

The weirdest thing of it all is that in the documentation, I saw that double quotes can be escaped with this function, so I tried to put another one in first position in the string to check if it would be escaped :

`$mystring = '"' . $mystring;`

It is escaped, and I don't know why the others which come later in the strings aren't.

**Here is my current snippet (not escaping the double quotes) :**

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=" . HOST . ";dbname=" . DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

$data = $dbh -> query("MY SELECT REQUEST");
$result = $data -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$result_inter;

foreach ($result as $key => $entry) {
    foreach ($entry as $key2 => $entry_inter) {
        $new_value = $entry_inter;
        $new_value = strip_tags($new_value);
        $new_value = addslashes($new_value);
        $new_key[$key2] = $new_value;
    }
    $result_inter[$key] = $new_key;
}

$result = json_encode($result_inter);
echo($result);
```

If anyone has a clue about how to solve this, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Can you post the code that populates the array?

Comment: I'm populating the array by fetching data from my database with PDO, with `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

Comment: Need the whole loop (maybe simplified).. You can add it to the question. I think I know whats wrong but need the code.

Comment: `json_encode()` is perfectly capable of encoding strings. Why do you feel you need to re-encode its output?

Comment: @hek2mgl, I'll edit my question to add some code then.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I feel that I "need" to re-encode its output because of those double-quotes which are not escaped, and result in an unvalid JSON. (double-quotes inside attributes are not supported)

Comment: `addslashes()` corrupts your input data but, since you do it before `json_encode()`, you'll JSON will be 100% valid. It'll contain corrupted data but it'll be well formed. Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) if you don't believe me.

Comment: yepp, remove the addslashes call

Comment: It is still not valid, because there are attributes such as `"some-attribute":"blah blah blah "double-quoted blah blah inside" blah"` in there. So nope, JSON Lint says it's not valid.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to put it in JSON, use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead of any witchcraft with `addslashes`.

Comment: I'm already using json_encode... And the resulting JSON is not well formed because of the remaining double-quotes.

Comment: @Selphira: It is impossible for the output of `json_encode` to not be well-formed. You are doing something else with it, and evidently that something is wrong. What is it?

Comment: I'm currently doing a simple loop, with `strip_tags` calls, in order to remove the html tags from some attributes, because some of them do contain HTML content, and I thought it might conflict so I'm doing those tests for removing double quotes on tags-free strings.

Do you think it might be the actual cause?

(I also removed them because on `echo`, the html would be formatted and I find it annoying to debug.)

Comment: @Selphira - Yes, that's the actual cause almost for sure. An HTML string encoded as JSON is no longer HTML: it's JSON.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I also tried not to strip those slashes, and still, the resulting JSON was not valid. What should I do to escape those quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mess around with `strip_tags`, `addslashes` or any other function. If you want to encode your array in JSON, simply use `json_encode`.

You probably missed the fact that there are different available options like `JSON_HEX_APOS` or `JSON_HEX_QUOT` if you want to escape quotes.

ex:

```
$string = "'apo'";
echo json_encode($string , JSON_HEX_APOS);
```

will output `"\u0027apo\u0027"`.

I think that's what you're looking for.